# i want to get this output : 2*2 = 4

Tags: python

```
a= int(input('Multiplication: '))
print(end="")
b= int(input(' * '))
print(' = ',a*b,end="")
```

Is there a way to make an input statement in 1 line to get the value of a and b
{a] * {b} =

I'm trying to make the input in line with the text and a and b are in between a string

Comment: So, you want to ask for values of `a` and `b` on a single line with one call to `input()`?

Comment: im looking for a way to add 2 input values to add in between text in the same line not print

Comment: yes @JonSG thats it and a string (text) between

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code to get the value of `a` and `b` when entering them on the same line and print the desired result.

```
a, b = map(int, input().split())
result = a * b
print(f"Multiplication: {a} * {b} = {result}")
```

Comment: like f string for print , is there a way to do that for input

Comment: @MoohaYT_Art
You can try the code by following the link below. It allows you to enter input and print the results in just 1 line.
You will need to add the msvcrt library and will have to do extra work to remove the line break when pressing enter: https://ideone.com/sbRJVA